# How to hide the border for specified rows of a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I want to hide the border for a specific rows of a table.How to do it?
Any Idea?
 Sample code is Highly Appreciated.

Comment: You have a lot of questions without an accepted answer. Please [go back through your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1468481/laxman-chowdary?tab=questions&sort=votes) and accept answers that helped you. Also, do show what you have tried.

Comment: and then google your problems first...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the CSS property border on the `<td>`s following the `<tr>`s you do not want to have the border.

In my example I made a class `noBorder` that I gave to one `<tr>`. Then I use a simple selector `tr.noBorder td` to make the border go away for all the `<td>`s that are inside of `<tr>`s with the `noBorder` class by assigning `border: 0`.

Note that you do not need to provide the unit (i.e. `px`) if you set something to `0` as it does not matter anyway. Zero is just zero.

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
tr.noBorder td {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the output as an image:

[image: Output from HTML]

Comment: @vikrantx is right, the direct property is `border-style`, although `border: dashed` will also work as you do not need to use the full `border: 1px dashed black` form.

Comment: Really Helpful ----- MVP

Answer (score 27):

I use this with good results:

```
border-style:hidden;
```

It also works for:

```
border-right-style:hidden; /*if you want to hide just a border on a cell*/
```

Example:

```html
<style type="text/css">
      table, th, td {
       border: 2px solid green;
      }
      tr.hide_right > td, td.hide_right{
        border-right-style:hidden;
      }
      tr.hide_all > td, td.hide_all{
        border-style:hidden;
      }
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="hide_right">11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td class="hide_all">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hide_right">
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hide_all">
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add programatically noborder class to specific row to hide it

```
<style>
     .noborder
      {
        border:none;
      }
    </style>

<table>

    <tr>
       <th>heading1</th>
       <th>heading2</th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
       <td>content1</td>
       <td>content2</td>
    </tr>
    /*no border for this row */
    <tr class="noborder">
       <td>content1</td>
       <td>content2</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add these lines of codes here to hide a row,

Either you can write `border:0` or `border-style:hidden;` `border: none` or it will happen the same thing

```html
<style type="text/css">
              table, th, td {
               border: 1px solid;
              }
              
              tr.hide_all > td, td.hide_all{
                 border: 0;
                
              }
          }
        </style>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class= hide_all>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td>$150</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Swanson</td>
        <td>$300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cleveland</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td>$250</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

running these lines of codes can solve the problem easily