# How to create semantic CSS table/rows without borders?

Tags: semantic-ui

the closest I have come is to use "very basic" attributes, but the rows still have borders between them.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Try `border-collapse: collapse` on your `table` element.

Comment: your question is not clear.
check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517432/how-to-hide-the-border-for-specified-rows-of-a-table

Comment: folks, I am talking about specifically semantic-ui product -- not generic HTML tables

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517432/how-to-hide-the-border-for-specified-rows-of-a-table

Answer (score 7):

based on https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1980

Using `ui very basic table` class and this custom css:

`.ui.table tr td { border-top: 0px !important; }`